# How to save a search for later reuse

Tags: support

I like to browse upvoted, non duplicate, non closed questions without any answer. Typing in the advanced search every time again is annoying. Is there a way to save and reuse searches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saved searches in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163341/187824)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmark the search in your web browser. Jeff Atwood [has recommended a similar approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107792/210346) for bookmarking answers.

Comment: Silly me. I am the one at work always arguing that searches must be bookmarkable and did not notice that it is well possible on SO. :-(